# Notifications in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, thread-synchronization

I am a java programmer and I am having a conceptual doubt in threads.
I just want to know a thread will enter into which state in 2 conditions.

1. When you join a thread in which state will the joined thread enter into?
2. When a waiting thread is notified, it will enter into which state. Runnable or Running?

Thanks

1. Details of 1st question

In a program main thread is running, it creates 3 new thread named "A", "B" & "C". Then all the 3 threads "A", "B" and "C" thread join the "main" thread. Now main thread is in which state.

1. Details of 2nd question

This is sample code for wait & notification.
If supposing 2 threads "A" & "B" start using "hello" object. 
First B thread executes and is put into "waiting" state.
Then "A" thread executes & notifies "B" thread. 
Now the "waiting" thread B will enter into which state. Will it directly enter Running state because the object lock is released or first will it move to Runnable and then move to Running state?
Note there is one more thread the main thread which is also present

```
public class Hello {
     int x;
     boolean flag=false;
     synchronized public void push(int x)
     {
         if(flag)
         {
             try
             {
                 wait();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println(e);
             }
         }
         this.x=x;
         System.out.println(x +"is pushed");
         flag=true;
         notify();
     }

    synchronized public void pop()
     {
        if(!flag)
         {
            try
             {
                wait();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println(e);
             }
         }
         System.out.println(x +"is poped");
         flag=false;
         notify();

     }

}

class A implements Runnable
{
     Hello h=null;
     A(Hello h,String name)
     {
         this.h=h;
         Thread t1=new Thread(this,name);
         t1.start();
     }
     public void run()
     {
         int a=1;
         for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
         {
             h.push(a++);
         }
     }
}

class B implements Runnable
{
     Hello h=null;
     B(Hello h,String name)
     {
         this.h=h;
         Thread t2=new Thread(this,name);
         t2.start();
     }
     public void run()
     {
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
         {
            h.pop();
         }
     }
};

public class WaitAndNotifyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
         A obj1=new A(h,"A");
         B obj2=new B(h,"B");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The joined thread will not even notice that you are joining it. The *joining* thread will enter the *waiting* state.
2. The notified thread will initially enter the *blocked* state as it will be added to the waiting set of the monitor it has previously executed `Object#wait` against. By definition `Object#wait` can only be executed against an object on which you are currently owning the lock and you must reacquire that lock to resume from `wait`.

Note that the difference between *Runnable* and *Running* is a detail of the thread scheduler.  The `Thread.State` enum does not distinguish between these.

Comment: @Mikhail I *have* reviewed the sources, over and over through the years. So please, which sources do you have in mind, **specifically**? BTW the second point is specified by the JLS, so no sources need to be reviewed to give an authoritative answer.